# Best way / practice to organize code for validation method C#

Tags: c#, coding-style, nested-if

I'm wondering what would be the best way or organize code when you doing the validation?

Nested if or return at the first place your validation failed?

**This is the first way I did, focus on the successful scenario, using nested if**

```
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value!= null && value.GetType().Equals(typeof(string)))
        {
            var text = value.ToString();
            if (Regex.IsMatch(text, "^[-+]?[0-9]{1,2}.?[0-9]{0,6}?,[-+]?[0-9]{1,3}.?[0-9]{0,6}?$"))
            {
                var cordinations = text.Split(',');
                if (cordinations.Length == 2)
                {
                    decimal latitude = 0;
                    decimal longitude = 0;
                    if (decimal.TryParse(cordinations[0].Replace(" ", string.Empty), out latitude) && decimal.TryParse(cordinations[1].Replace(" ", string.Empty), out longitude))
                    {
                        if ((latitude >= -90 && latitude <= 90) && (longitude >= -180 && longitude <= 180))
                            return ValidationResult.Success;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new ValidationResult(Admin.ResourceManager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName));
    }
```

**This is the second way I did, focus on the failed scenarios**

```
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value==null)
            return new ValidationResult(Admin.ResourceManager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName));
        if (!value.GetType().Equals(typeof(string)))
            return new ValidationResult(Admin.ResourceManager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName));

        var text = value.ToString();
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(text, "^[-+]?[0-9]{1,2}.?[0-9]{0,6}?,[-+]?[0-9]{1,3}.?[0-9]{0,6}?$"))
            return new ValidationResult(Admin.ResourceManager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName));

        var cordinations = text.Split(',');
        if (cordinations.Length != 2)
            return new ValidationResult(Admin.ResourceManager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName));

        decimal latitude = 0;
        decimal longitude = 0;
        if (!decimal.TryParse(cordinations[0].Replace(" ", string.Empty), out latitude) || 
            !decimal.TryParse(cordinations[1].Replace(" ", string.Empty), out longitude))
            return new ValidationResult(Admin.ResourceManager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName));

        if (!(latitude >= -90 && latitude <= 90) || !(longitude >= -180 && longitude <= 180))
            return new ValidationResult(Admin.ResourceManager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName)); .
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
```

Which one would be considered as the best practice this day. Or any other way to do this. I would be really appreciate your ideas, may be any reference Microsoft suggests?

Comment: Second way more easy to read then first one

Comment: First of all, your code will throw NRE, if `value` is `null` - `value is string` would be enough.

Comment: When you read second way you can recognize that every validation can be extracted in the own method, then reading will be more easy, no need to read all details of validation

Comment: And I think may be this question is more for [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Fabio - Thanks, got the point. I'll post this question there too.

Comment: @Dennis - Thanks, I made the change you also think the second way is the best?

Comment: @Geeganage: 2nd one is much more readable, than several nested `if`s. But it's really opinion-based. )

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the second way is better as it prevent nesting and is a more friendly code, meaning the code can be easily maintained. However you could improve it may adding a `ValidationResult` at the top and update that instance at each validation to finally having only one return statement at the bottom.

What i mean is something like this:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var rtn = new ValidationResult();

    if (value==null)
        rtn  = ValidationResult(Admin.ResourceManager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName));
    if (!value.GetType().Equals(typeof(string)))
        rtn =  ValidationResult(Admin.ResourceManager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName));

    var text = value.ToString();
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(text, "^[-+]?[0-9]{1,2}.?[0-9]{0,6}?,[-+]?[0-9]{1,3}.?[0-9]{0,6}?$"))
        rtn  = ValidationResult(Admin.ResourceManager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName));

    var cordinations = text.Split(',');
    if (cordinations.Length != 2)
        rtn  = ValidationResult(Admin.ResourceManager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName));

    decimal latitude = 0;
    decimal longitude = 0;
    if (!decimal.TryParse(cordinations[0].Replace(" ", string.Empty), out latitude) || 
        !decimal.TryParse(cordinations[1].Replace(" ", string.Empty), out longitude))
        rtn  = ValidationResult(Admin.ResourceManager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName));

    if (!(latitude >= -90 && latitude <= 90) || !(longitude >= -180 && longitude <= 180))
        rtn  =  ValidationResult(Admin.ResourceManager.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName)); .

    if(rtn.HasNoError) rtn = ValidationResult.Success; // or something of the like

    return rtn;
}
```

This aids you in debugging by preventing the code from returning from somewhere in the middle of the method. Hope it helps

Comment: Initialization instance in the top is useless, because every validation will re-initialize it with new instance. You can just declare the variable at the top `ValidationResult result;`

Comment: Returning validation in the "middle" is better approach, because it removes redundant validations for value which already have validation result.

Comment: Thanks @Hisham 
Doesn't this create the validation result object, even that doesn't need? I mean when the validation is success.
And additional if also has to use.
When someone reading from the top he/she has to read to the end of the method to know what is returning.